# VsPackage Global Service Lifestyle

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vspackage

I am reading this documentation about how to make VsPackage Global service:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166804(v=vs.100).aspx

I would like to create structure as sort of "cache" that would be used by my inplementation ICompletionSource. If I understand things corectly classes implementing **ICompletionSourceProvider** and **ICompletionSource** are instancied with new editor window / completion session. I want cache across all sessions that would load data once, update then when needed but that would not be gone with each session/editor.

That brings me to the question. What is Global Service *instance lifestyle*?

I am looking for some kind of *"singleton"* object that is created on Package initialisation, outlives **ICompletionSource** instances, for which it should provide pre-cached data. It would be also nice if the object was able to subscribe to project change events (mainly adding/removing files). Is VsPackage Global Service suitable for this? What is the best practice here?

I am trying to do my reading, but there is lot to look into here.

Answer (score 1):

So by the sound of it you're really in the MEF world of things with `Import` and `Export` attributes. For MEF in VS, anything `Export`ed (unless stated otherwise which you control) is a singleton which once created will live for the lifetime of the process. It's very common to have a internal type you MEF export and import internally to provide access to shared state.